# python implicit namespace packages are not installing with setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, setuptools, python-3.4

Using Python 3.4 and Setuptools, I'm trying to get namespace packages to work correctly as defined in PEP 420.  My directory structure looks something like this:

- project
  - __init__.py
  - core
    - several .py files
  - logging
    - com1
      - several .py files
    - com2
      - several .py files
  - interface
    - misc files

When using setuptools `find_package()` function, it finds the "project" package, but it doesn't install any of the folders (implicit sub-packages) inside of "project".  When I unzip the .egg file, all I see is the __init__.py file inside, none of the subdirectories or files.

I could just put an __init__.py in every directory, but since those files would all be empty and I don't like the way it makes the structure work, I'm trying to avoid that.

If I move to just outside of my "project" directory, and run the following, it works

```
python -m project.logging.com1.myfile
```

but anywhere else it doesn't work, because setuptools isn't installing the sub-directories (implicit namespaces) that don't have __init__.py in them.

How can I make setuptools install my implicit namespace packages correctly? Would I just need to tell it to install all files inside the directory and that will be good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the initial pull request that added PEP 420 support to setuptools was [rejected](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/pull-request/37). There is an open discussion on the best way to merge in PEP 420 support on [another issue](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/97), but at the moment, it doesn't appear that implicit namespaces are supported.

Comment: provided links are broken

Answer (score 0):

Implicit namespace packages are not supported by `find_packages`. However, all that `find_packages` does is a return a list of `dotted.package.name`s. You can still list your packages explicitly.